# Looping with Promises in JS

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, parse-server

I am trying to run queries inside a for loop in nodejs and each iteration of the for loop runs one query. The queries are done with a "get()" method that returns a Promise. In my function (that contains this for loop), I am returning the promise returned by the get() method like so:

`for(var i=0; i < productIds.length; i++) {
return queryObject.get(productIds[i]).then(//handle result)
}`

but this returns after the first iteration and doesn't continue for the rest of the iterations. How do I solve this issue?

For context, I am using Parse's Cloud Functions.

Comment: Share a bigger code snippet.

Comment: I am away from my computer atm but I'm happy to answer any queries you have

Comment: Come back later and share more code.

Comment: why the async-await tag

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully it gives you little more information

Comment: @zebnat I read another similar question that was answered with async-await but I'm not sure if it applies here. I'm very new to JS

Comment: @krishnakeshan it makes sense that your code snippet ends after the first iteration, because `return` always stops a function. What do you _want_ to return?

Comment: If I don't have the 'return' before the get() function, it does not return the value returned inside the get() method I use inside the then() of the first get ()

Comment: But you can only return "1 thing". Do you only want to return the first result, or do you want to return an array of all the results?

Comment: Basically I want to complete all the get() calls and only continue the function when the last get() has finished

Comment: I see. That helps me get an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to build up a promise chain like so:

```
let chain = Promise.resolve();

for (i=0; i<1000; i++) {
   chain = chain.then(()=>queryObject.get(objectId))
}

chain.then(()=>{ /* do something once all queries have returned a result */})
```

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this... please explain.

Answer (score 3):

The answer given by TLP demonstrates [Promise Chaining](https://javascript.info/promise-chaining), and will work for you here. However, I'll explain a little more about what is happening and provide an alternative answer.

First, let's understand why your code fails to do what you want:

```
for(var i=0; i < productIds.length; i++) {
    return queryObject.get(productIds[i]).then(//handle result)
}
```

You want the code to run for every productId; however, you are telling the code to return, exiting the for loop, in the very first iteration. Think about the following:

```
for(var i=0; i < productIds.length; i++) {
    return productIds[i];
}
```

Removing the promises from the picture makes it a bit easier to see the error. This for loop is equivalent to:

```
return productIds[0];
```

Likewise, your code is equivalent to:

```
return queryObject.get(productIds[0]).then(//handle result)
```

Assuming you see the error here, now I'll point out a small error in your thought process that got you here. In your post you say:

> I am returning the promise returned by the get() method like so:

You refer to a single promise returned from "the" call to the get() method, but you are actually hoping to call the get() method many times, producing *many promises*.

If all of this makes sense then your next step is to decide whether:

1. You need to run code after ALL promises have completed (that uses the full list of retrieved data).
2. You only need to run code per completed promise (that uses only the data retrieved from the specific promise).

You achieve #1 using Promise Chaining, as illustrated by TLP's answer. You can achieve #2 by simply removing the "return" from your code, i.e.:

```
for(var i=0; i < productIds.length; i++) {
    queryObject.get(productIds[i]).then(//handle result)
}
```

Comment: I think this should work. I'll try both methods and update you as well

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities, parallel and serial. I'll show both:

```
async function serial(productIds) {
  for(const productId of productIds) {
      await queryObject.get(productId).then(//handle result)
  }
}

function parallel(productIds) {
  return Promise.all(
     productIds.map( productI => queryObject.get(productId).then(//handle result)
  );
}
```

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: i tried this method and it gets each product sequentially but the main method that I call this from continues executing after the first iteration of the for loop. how do i make it such that the main function continues executing only after the serial() function has finished executing all queries